# Somar valores filtrados de uma tabela html com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma **tbody** com varias **tr** dessas:

```
<tr class="odd">

    <td class="id-despesa">
        <p class="orig">
            <?php echo $exibe2->id ?>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="data-despesa">
        <p class="orig">
            <?php echo $exibe2->data ?>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="funcionario-despesa">
        <p class="orig">
            <?php echo $exibe2->funcionario ?>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="valor-rep">
        <p class="orig">
            <?php echo $exibe2->valorRep ?>
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Como podem perceber, os dados da tabela estão sendo puxados do BD, mas enfim, oque eu preciso é somar todos os valores das td's com class **valor-rep** onde **funcionario-despesa** for igual a "x". Seria o equivalente a isso em PHP: **SELECT valor-rep FROM tabela WHERE funcionario-despesa=='x'** e depois somar todos os valores recebidos, acho que conseguiram intendem oque quis dizer com essa comparação.

Eu ja tenho uma funcão para somar todos os valores de **valor-rep** como podem ver:

```
var valorComSoma = 0;
$('#boxCom .valor-rep').each(function (i) {   
    valorComSoma = parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')) +valorComSoma;
});
```

Precisaria meio que adicionar um filtro nessa função ou algo parecido, como citei anteriormente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exemplo funcional.
Explicação : Pegando todas as TR's e verificando qual é do tipo 'X' e somando apenas as que atendem ao mesmo.

```js
$(function(){
  var total = 0;
  $('tr').each(function(){
    var funcDespesa = $(this).find('.funcionario-despesa > p').text().trim();
    if(funcDespesa === 'x'){
      total += parseInt($(this).find('.valor-rep > p').text().trim());
    }
  });
  
  $('.total').html(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">

    <td class="id-despesa">
        <p class="orig">
            AAAA
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="data-despesa">
        <p class="orig">
            99/99/9999
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="funcionario-despesa">
        <p class="orig">
            x
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="valor-rep">
        <p class="orig">
            50
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">

    <td class="id-despesa">
        <p class="orig">
            AAAA
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="data-despesa">
        <p class="orig">
            99/99/9999
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="funcionario-despesa">
        <p class="orig">
            y
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="valor-rep">
        <p class="orig">
            130
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">

    <td class="id-despesa">
        <p class="orig">
            AAAA
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="data-despesa">
        <p class="orig">
            99/99/9999
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="funcionario-despesa">
        <p class="orig">
            x
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="valor-rep">
        <p class="orig">
            260
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="total">
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito Mateus Veloso, muito obrigado!